# How comprehend ' threshold of managed heap is continuously adjusted as the process runs' in GC?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, clr

When I Read this article，I don't comprehend the statement which I bold && italic it as follow:
**Conditions for a garbage collection**

Garbage collection occurs when one of the following conditions is true:

1. The system has low physical memory.
2. The memory that is used by allocated objects on the managed heap surpasses   an acceptable threshold. ***This threshold is continuously adjusted as the process runs***.
3. The GC.Collect method is called. In almost all cases, you do
   not have to call this method, because the garbage collector runs
   continuously. This method is primarily used for unique situations
   and testing.

But there is another limit(ephemeral segment value) for GC's Ephemeral generations.

### |--------------------------------|32-bit  |64-bit

|**Workstation GC**                 | 16 MB  |256 MB

|**Server GC**                       |64 MB   |4 GB
|**Server GC with > 4 logical CPUs**  |32 MB   |2 GB
|**Server GC with > 8 logical CPUs**  |16 MB   |1 GB

=======================================================================

### Question

I want to know:

1. is there a relation between the GC's ephemeral segment value Value
   && managed heap threshold value?
2. The managed heap threshold Value is ?(max & min)
3. Is there a detail for the threshold adjust algorithm?

=======================================================================

### Reference

[GC on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=VS.110).aspx#workstation_and_server_garbage_collection)